# Кто написал "Честное слово"?

Tags: литература

Дали список литературы. Написано, Гайдар "Честное слово", но интернет выдаёт, что это произведение написал Пантелеев?

Answer (score 3):

Автор сборника рассказов "Честное слово" и рассказа, давшего название этому сборнику, действительно Леонид Пантелеев.

[ПРОЧТУ.РУ](http://prochtu.ru/uslishu.php?avtor=331&kniga=2)

Книга «Честное слово» автора: Леонид Пантелеев.
Описание книги
Про мальчика и про его крепкое честное слово...

РАССКАЗЫ О ДЕТЯХ

Эти рассказы давно уже стали классикой, на них воспиталось не одно 
поколение читателей. Они издавались в сериях "Библиотека пионера", "Золотая 
библиотека", в сборниках, представляющих советскую детскую литературу за 
рубежом. Дети, их судьбы, характеры всегда волновали писателя. В каждом из 
ребят, независимо от возраста, Л. Пантелеев видит личность, с уважением и 
пониманием относится к трудностям, с которыми они сталкиваются на нелегком 
пути взросления. Какими же представляет своих героев Л. Пантелеев? Он 
считает, что самые лучшие человеческие качества - честность, храбрость, 
достоинство - проявляются не только в исключительных обстоятельствах, но и в 
самой обычной, будничной обстановке. Вот почему написанный в мирные дни 
рассказ "Честное слово" о верности маленького мальчика данному слову так 
актуально прозвучал в первые дни войны. Его не только опубликовали, но и 
читали по радио.

Answer (score 1):

У меня "интернет" выдает, что этот вопрос уже задавался везде, где только можно. И хоть бы слово в формулировке поменяли.

Что за список-то?

У Пантелеева есть такой рассказ, известный, но я не уверен, что его нет у Гайдара. Что-то там про мальчика, который что-то разбил или испортил... А потом дал честное слово, что это не он. А может это и не Гайдара. И не "Честное слово". Надо по собранию сочинений посмотреть. Если это действительно ваш Вопрос, а не спамовая перепечатка из Инета для получения давно заготовленного ответа от знакомого (или своего же клона), я уточню. Хотя вряд ли в школе дадут читать рассказ Гайдара, который не "на слуху".

Нет, не обнаружил я у Гайдара такого рассказа.

Comment: [«Голубая чашка» — рассказ Аркадия Гайдара для среднего школьного возраста](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Эту я помню. Нет, я искал что-то другое, с другой моралью. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Учителя, которые предлагают этот список, сами не читали предлагаемые произведения! Если бы читали, то  исправили бы ошибку! Конечно, Пантелеев написал трогательный рассказ о маленьком мальчике, точнее о маленьком мужчине, который умеет держать честное слово.